# difference between two dictionarys using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm have been playing around with linq this morning and have a questions about comparing two dictionarys.  I want to compare two dicionarys and return the difference.  I am able to produce my desired output by minuplating the query in my foreach loop.  However, I'm wondering if there is an operator that would allow me to simplify this a bit more. Below I have listed the code i would like to simplify.

```
var _ItemsBefore = new SortedDictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 12 }, { 2, 12 } };
var _ItemsAfter  = new SortedDictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 11 }, { 2,  8 } { 3,  1 } };

foreach(var item in _ItemsAfter.Except(_ItemsBefore))
{
  if(_ItemBefore.ContainsKey(item.Key))
    Console.WriteLine(string.format("{0} {1}", item.Key, _ItemsAfter[item.Key] -_ItemsBefore[item.Key]));
  else
    Console.WriteLine(string.format("{0} {1}", item.Key, item.Value)
}

results
1 -1
2 -4
3  1
```

Comment: If first dictionary has {5,10} what is your output result?

Comment: It would be the same result.  I'm only interested in what has changed.  You you think of this in terms of inventory. Before is all the items at the beginning of the day, After is items at the end.  You may have sold items or recieved items during the day.  I am interested in what i have sold and what i have recieved?  I hope i am making this clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your requirements, This is a linq version, but it's not as readable as your `for` loop version:

```
var result = _ItemsAfter
             .Except(_ItemsBefore)
             .Select(x => _ItemsBefore.ContainsKey(x.Key) ?
                     new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x.Key, x.Value - _ItemsBefore[x.Key]) :
                     new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Saeed, I was thinking there was a simplier format.  I'll stick with my foreach loop for readablity.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to be careful about how you store a lack of items, if you are deleting values when you have no inventory then you will not print out that reduction in inventory. However if you are storing 0, then you should not have a problem.

Comment: this will never be the case sir. My items example in the commnt above was just to clarify what i was after.  Before and After are simply snapshots of the dictionaries at a specific time.  No adding or removing, just comparing.

Comment: @poco: Ah, just making sure the fact that data in Before, but not in After not being included in the results was appropriate.